# How to check If the next element in an array is null - Java

Tags: java

I'm creating quite a large, multiple class program and just need to find out if the next element in the array exists for one of my methods. (i.e.  if `i` is the last element).

My code:

```
if (eMessageArray[i + 1] != null) {
    temp = stringShuffle(eMessageArray[i], eMessageArray[i + 1]);
    eMessageArray[i] = temp;
} else if (eMessageArray[i + 1] == null) {
    temp = stringShuffle(eMessageArray[i], "NULL");
    eMessageArray[i] = temp;
}
```

Comment: And what is the problem with your code? `eMessageArray[i+1]==null` seems like right test. Also your second `if` is redundant since only case in which `else` would be executed is when `(eMessageArray[i+1]` is `null`.

Comment: ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException Basically by the time the array has iterated to the end, I'm trying to access i+1 which is the same as eMessageArray.length   . So I'm trying access an element that doesnt exist

Comment: Are you running into an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException? If so, make sure that you're not trying to access the next element if i is the last element.

Comment: So don't test element after last one. Either limit your `i` to `array.lenbth-1` or add condition like `i+1<array.length`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What causes a java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException and how do I prevent it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554734/what-causes-a-java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-and-how-do-i-prevent-it)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when `i` points to the the last element of the array, then there is no element `i+1`, because the array is not long enough. The solution is to stop iterating with `i` at the second last index, so that `i+1` is always a valid index. This is done with the `...length - 1` as follows:

```
for (int i = 0; i < eMessageArray.length - 1; i++) { // important: - 1 to omit last index for i
    if (eMessageArray[i+1]!=null){
        temp = stringShuffle(eMessageArray[i], eMessageArray[i+1]);
    } else {
        temp=stringShuffle(eMessageArray[i], "NULL");
    }
    eMessageArray[i]=temp;
}
```

Comment: Thanks man, this is of course what I should do, quite a quick fix! Didn't think about it...

Answer (score 0):

Generally when trying to access the array index out of bounds there might be some garbage values present instead, which would though not be `null` yet meaningless to be accessed. You would want to define the `bounds` of an array if you want to use it && provide that check inside your iteration for the bound range.